# Cannot read property 'style' of null - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have set up a controller in which I call a function defined in a service.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    FilterDataService.checkForFilters($scope.mediaTypeList, 'filterAddMediaType');
  });
```

Below is the function:

```
this.checkForFilters = function(list, filterSection) {
  if (list < 1) {
    document.getElementById(filterSection).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(filterSection).style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
};
```

I have no issues calling and getting results from this function after my view and controller has loaded. However when I call this function on page view+controller load I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

The error is with this line

```
document.getElementById(filterSection).style.display = 'none';
```

I figured the issue was because I am trying to set a style on a div element which has not loaded yet so I put in the following:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {...
```

However this did not solve my issue. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried the following:

```
angular.element('#' + filterSection).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById(filterSection).style.display = 'none';
    });
```

Comment: Check whether the loaded page contains 'filterAddMediaType' div

Comment: You're using angular the same way you would use jQuery. Just don't. Stop doing DOM manipulation. Define a model, and use ng-show in your view to show and hide elements based on the model values: `<div id="filterAddMediaType" ng-show="mediaList > 0">...</div>`

Comment: @SANN3 I've checked and it does have that element present.

Comment: @JB Nizet this is so true! Let me rework this using ng-model...

Comment: @ocajian you don't need any ng-model. ng-model is for form fields.

Comment: @JB Nizet Sorry yes you are correct, there are fields inside my div but they have nothing to do with what I'm achieving here. I posted a solution to my question with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ngClass instead of the traditional jQuery way. Something like this should work.

```
<div ng-class="[{'display-none-class' : $scope.mediaTypeList &&
 $scope.mediaTypeList.length > 0},
{'display-inlineb-class' : !$scope.mediaTypeList ||
 $scope.mediaTypeList.length === 0}]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After receiving help from @JB Nizet I came up with the following solution. Initially I was trying to achieve my results using dom manipulation which is not the angular way.

This is what I did to fix this:

Controller function call:

```
$scope.filterAddSectionSource = FilterDataService.checkForFilters($scope.mediaTypeList);
```

Service function:

```
this.checkForFilters = function(list) {
  if (list < 1) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Dom element:

```
<div class="filterInfoSection" id="filterAddSectionSource" ng-show="filterAddSectionSource">
```